# Error: unrecognised option 'rsession-which-r

Tags: installation, server, rstudio

We tried with using the path `rsession-which-r =/usr/local/bin/R` as mentioned in the installation and configuration document, but we're getting the below error

```
[root@server_name rstudio]#  rstudio-server verify-installation
rstudio-server stop/waiting
Error reading /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf: unrecognised option 'rsession-which-r'
rstudio-server start/running, process 24260
```

When we commented out the `'rsession-which-r'` in the rsession config file, then  we're able to log in from the R studio server (which is web based) and unable to connect to teradata from there.

We are are also having trouble trying to configure

```
rsession-ld-library-path=/usr/local/bin/lib64/
```

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf file, secondly you need to restart the server, finally you can just stop and verify the installation

```sh
sudo rm /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf 
sudo systemctl start rstudio-server.service
sudo rstudio-server stop
sudo systemctl start rstudio-server.service
```

help it will work for you!